# Как убрать ошибку JS в PHPMyAdmin?

Tags: javascript, phpmyadmin

Установил новую версию PHPMyAdmin. В целом все OK, но в консоли вылезает ошибка JS:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null

Файл с ошибкой: si.js:123

При этом в левой части рядом со значками меню вылезает нескрываемая иконка загрузки (круг с мигающими линиями). Не знаю, связано ли это с данной ошибкой или нет.

Кто сталкивался с подобным?

Comment: Вылезает. Писать грамотно - это легко.

Comment: Думаю, что стоит добавить строку под номером 123 из файла *si.js*, а лучше метод, в котором содержится эта строка.

Comment: как я понял, там ругается касперский, в некоторых браузерах эта ошибка не встречается.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Выяснил в чем было дело, ругался Касперский, который сейчас автоматом подключает свое проверочные скрипты через браузер. После переезда на протокол HTTPS ошибка исчезла.